# When I click a button I need to go to another page for this I am using useHistory hook but it's not working properly in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React project In my project I have a Home page in that I have a Button when I click the Button I need to go to Login page for this I am using useHistory hook but it is not working fine.
So someone please help me to acheive this

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home';
import Login from './Pages/Login/Login';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path=''><Home></Home></Route>
          <Route path='/login'><Login></Login></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                                <li className="nav-item active">
                                    <Link className='nav-link' to=''>Home</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

This is Home.js'

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Home.css';

const Home = () => {
    let history = useHistory()

    const relocate = () => {
        history.push('/login')
    }
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <h1>Home works</h1>
                    <button onClick={relocate} className='btn btn-primary'>Go to Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

This is Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Login.css';

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='one'>
                        <h1>Welcome to Login page</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean not working properly? Try adding exact to the login route

```
 <Route exact path="/login">
     <Login />
 </Route>
```

Also the path for the home route should be `path="/"`

```
<Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
</Route>
```

not `path=''`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `path` of `<Home/>` to `'/'`

`<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

Also, you don't need to use the useHistory hook when you already have access to `history` props

```
const Home = (props) => {
    const relocate = () => {
       props.history.push("/login");
    };

   // ...
}
```